# How to update pure function?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to do the following: I want to write a function `translate(f, c)` that takes a given function `f` (say we know `f` is a function of a single variable `x`) and a constant `c` and returns a *new function* that computes `f(x+c)`.

I know that in Python functions are first-class objects and that I can pass `f` as an argument, but I can't think of a way to do this without passing `x` too, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Your goal is to return a function, you get `x` by defining a function `h` inside of `translate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is for translate to return a function *instance*.

```
def translate(f, c):
    def func(x):
        return f(x + c)
    return func
```

Now the variable `x` is "free", and the names `f` and `c` are coming from an enclosing scope.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
def translate_func(f, c):
    return lambda x: f(x + c)
```

To be used like, e.g.:

```
import math


g = translate_func(math.sin, 10)
print(g(1) == math.sin(10 + 1))
# True
```

---

## EDIT

Note that this design pattern of a function taking a function as a parameter and returning another function is quite common in Python and goes by the name of "function decoration", with an associated convenience syntax. See [PEP318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) for more info on it.

Comment: Hum. Interesting. Is there any performance benefit over defining a function? Or is it just in essence shorter due to the one liner return statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
def transalte(f, c):
   def _inner(x):
      return f(x+c)
   return _inner
```

Comment: Where this does work it is preferable to add some written context to this to describe why this works. Others may see this post and not understand the why.