# How to avoid infinite recursion in python class method

Tags: python, class, recursion

This is a follow-up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491338/how-to-update-pure-function-in-python).

I want a class that handles a function that can update itself. This is a simplified example, but I still end up with an infinite recursion:

```
def f(x):
    return x

class func:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def translate(self, c):
        def f_(x):
            return self.f(x + c)
        self.f = f_
```

It works only once:

```
>>> myfunc = func(f)
>>> myfunc.f(1)
1
>>> myfunc.translate(5)
>>> myfunc(1)
...
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The problem is that `self.f` calls `self.f`, which would not happen if `translate` were defined outside of a class:

```
def translate(f, c):
    def f_(x):
        return f(x+c)
    return f_
```

This works:

```
>>> f = translate(f, 5)
>>> f(1)
6
>>> f = translate(f,-5)
>>>f(1)
1
```

How can I make it work inside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd tried to write your outside-a-class `translate` closer to how you wrote your first `translate`:

```
def f(x):
    return x
def translate(c):
    global f
    def f_(x):
        return f(x+c)
    f = f_
translate(5)
f(1)
```

you would have gotten a RecursionError there too. Your outside-a-class `translate` worked because its `f_` looks for `f` in a local variable that doesn't get overwritten, rather than in the attribute or global you're about to rebind to your new `f_`.

Have your `translate` method look in a local variable too:

```
def translate(self, c):
    f = self.f
    def f_(self, x):
        return f(x+c)
    self.f = f_
```

(By the way, call this method enough times and you'll stack up so many layers of wrappers that you hit the recursion limit anyway. Stacking wrappers indefinitely is a bad idea.)

Comment: That's an insightful point. Is stacking wrappers avoidable somehow?

Comment: @Ziofil: For this case, you could just keep track of the offset on the instance. For more general transformations, no.

Comment: Depends on your requirements.  If you're going to apply the wrappers sequentially, you can keep and loop through a list of methods.  If you need to affect a value going both "down" and "up", you would need a more complicated solution (e.g. a `beforeNested` and `afterNested` method).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a closure, like you are doing without the class, by getting a reference to the original function object before updating the `self.f` attribute:

```
In [1]: def f(x):
   ...:     return x
   ...:
   ...: class func:
   ...:
   ...:     def __init__(self, f):
   ...:         self.f = f
   ...:
   ...:     def translate(self, c):
   ...:         f = self.f
   ...:         def f_(x):
   ...:             return f(x + c)
   ...:         self.f = f_
   ...:

In [2]: myfunc = func(f)

In [3]: myfunc.f(1)
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: myfunc.translate(5)

In [5]: myfunc.f(1)
Out[5]: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a quirk of Python name resolution.  Try something like this:

```
def translate(self, c):
    def f_(x, f=self.f):
        return f(x + c)
    self.f = f_
```

I wish I understood the issue well enough to give a concise explanation.  The rough version is that `self.f` always points to "the f method of self".  When you replace the f-method of self, it points to the new function and not the old one.  This is why it loops infinitely.

The kwargs trick works around the issue by creating a new variable in a special scope.  The value of `f` in `f=self.f` is self-contained in the function and stays with this specific function definition.  It gets set to the current value of `self.f` **when the function is defined**.  As a result, it doesn't get changed to point to the circular version of the function.